# Unable to install phpbrew mongo extension

Tags: php, phpbrew

I am trying to install phpbrew mongo extension

`phpbrew ext install mongo`

but I am getting error

`Error: Command failed: ./configure --with-php-config=/home/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.38/bin/php-config >> /home/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.38/ext/mongo///build.log 2>&1 returns:`

Please help

Comment: What does your `/home/.phpbrew/build/php-5.5.38/ext/mongo///build.log` say? There may be a missing header.

Comment: @PeterMellett, in my case, with the same error, trying to install intl, there is no output to the log. My error also ends with `returns:` I'd be interested if @user101 ever found a solution